# How to implement a default interface method that adds a value to the object instance

Tags: java, methods, interface, overriding, default

How do I implement void add(Number number) so it adds number to the object instance

```
public interface Numbers {
   static int toIntValue();
   static void fromIntValue(int value);
   default void add(Number number) {
        // what do i write here
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces don't know about object states. Typically, `add` would be an abstract method too. Why do you want to have it implemented in the interface?

Comment: What is the purpose of `fromIntValue`? Normally a method called `from` would have a return value.

Comment: it returns the value of the object instance as int

Comment: But as @khelwood said, it doesn't. The return type is `void`. Moreover, such a method would normally be `static`.

Comment: fromIntValue it assigns the object instance the parameter value

Comment: @nsol - It can't, if it's `static`. There's no instance to assign to. Before you added `static`, yes, it could have assigned to some field on the instance (**not** to the instance itself). But that would be odd for a method with that name. Conventions are a useful part of programming.

Comment: Now you've added the `static` keyword, but that doesn't make sense. Static methods cannot be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

You mostly cannot do this; interfaces do not have any state, and the notion of 'add a number' strongly implies that you wish to update the state.

This is one way to go:

```
public interface Number /* Isn't Numbers a really weird name? */ {
    int toIntValue();
    default int add(int otherValue) {
        return toIntValue() + otherValue;
    }
}
```

Here no state is changed; instead a new int is returned.

Another problem here is that the whole notion of abstracting away a numeric type is that there *is no default implementation of add*.

That's just basic math. Complex numbers are a kind of number; it is clearly impossible to write code that can add 2 complex numbers together **without knowing anything about complex numbers beforehand**.

What you *CAN* do is create add out of other primitives, except, 'add' is generally the convenient primitive. For example, here's a take on multiply that can work as a default method, though it is not at all efficient:

```
public interface Number {
    Number plus(Number a); /* an immutable structure makes more sense, in which case 'plus' is a better word than 'add' */
    default Number multiply(int amt) {
        if (amt == 0) return Number.ZERO; // Define this someplace.
        Number a = this;
        for (int i = 1; i < amt; i++) a = a.plus(this);
        return a;
    }
}
```

Here you've defined multiply in terms of plus.

Note that java already has an abstract number concept (`java.lang.Number`) and it indeed can do almost nothing, because trying to abstract math like this is hard in any language, and particularly so in java.

Comment: Ah, you see, I was mislead by the class name into thinking `Numbers` was a container for `Number` instances. But the other method names really don't support my interpretation.